# Track progress through namedtuple csv loop in python

Tags: python, loops, count, percentage

Using `collections.namedtuple`, the following Python code works through a csv file of identifiers (integers in a column named `ContentItemId`) for records in a database. An example record is https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/library/ephemera/21291.

Its purpose is to check a given id's HTTP status and write this to disk:

```py
import requests
from collections import namedtuple
import csv

with open('in.csv', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    all_records = namedtuple('rec', next(reader))
    records = [all_records._make(row) for row in reader]

    #Create output file
    with open('out.csv', mode='w+') as o:
        w = csv.writer(o)
        w.writerow(["ContentItemId","code"])

        count = 1
        for r in records:
            id   = r.ContentItemId
            url  = "https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/library/ephemera/" + id
            req  = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
            code = req.status_code
            w.writerow([id, code])
```

How can I print to the console the code's progress (ideally at 25%, 50%, and 75% junctures) through the latter loop? Also, if I add an unindented `print("Complete")` at the bottom, will that line be reached?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: Thanks for all the help. My (working!) code now looks like this:

```py
import csv
import requests
import pandas
import time
from collections import namedtuple
from tqdm import tqdm

with open('active_true_pub_no.csv', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    all_records = namedtuple('rec', next(reader))
    records = [all_records._make(row) for row in reader]

    with open('out.csv', mode='w+') as o:
        w = csv.writer(o)
        w.writerow(["ContentItemId","code"])

        num = len(records)
        print("Checking {} records...\n".format(num))

        with tqdm(total=num, bar_format="{percentage:3.0f}% {bar} [{n_fmt}/{total_fmt}]  ", ncols=64) as pbar:
            for r in records:
                pbar.update(1)
                id   = r.ContentItemId
                url  = "https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/library/ephemera/" + id
                req  = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
                code = req.status_code
                w.writerow([id, code])
                # time.sleep(.25)

print ('\nSummary: ')
df = pandas.read_csv("out.csv")
print(df['code'].value_counts())
```

I've used `pandas`' [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to summarise the reults at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To get a progress bar, use TQDM:

- [`tqdm`](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/)

#### Data (from `in.csv`):

```py
ContentItemId
21200
21201
21202
21203
21204
21205
21206
...
21296
21297
21298
21299
21300
```

#### Code:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
import csv
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm


with open('in.csv', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    all_records = namedtuple('rec', next(reader))
    records = [all_records._make(row) for row in reader]

    #Create output file
    with open('out.csv', mode='w+') as o:
        w = csv.writer(o)
        w.writerow(["ContentItemId","code"])

        count = 1

        with tqdm(total=len(records)) as pbar:
            for r in records:
                pbar.update(1)
                id   = r.ContentItemId
                url  = "https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/library/ephemera/" + id
                req  = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
                code = req.status_code
                w.writerow([id, code])
    print('Complete!')
```

- Note the addition of `with tqdm(total=len(records)) as pbar:` preceding the `for-loop`
- When run from the console, a progress bar will appear, showing percent complete.
- [image]
- [image]
- Note the left of the image, `21/101`, this is the count through the length of the `records` list.

  - `tqdm` provides a percentage progress bar and a count of `complete/total`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're referring to the percentage of records that have been processed. You can do the `print("Complete")` in the loop too.

```
count = 0
for r in records:
    id   = r.ContentItemId
    url  = "https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/library/ephemera/" + id
    req  = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    code = req.status_code
    w.writerow([id, code])
    count += 1
    if count == len(records):
        print("Complete")
    # Need the round in case list of records isn't divisible by 4
    elif count % round(len(records) / 4) == 0:
        # Round fraction to two decimal points and multiply by 100 for
        # integer percentage
        progress = int(round(count / len(records), 2) * 100)
        print("{}%".format(progress))
```

Comment: I get this output from running the code with your additions on a test file containing ten ContentItemIDs:

0%
0%
0%
0%
Complete

Comment: That's odd. The only culprit I can think of is a misalignment of the parentheses in the `print` statement. I edited the answer to calculate progress on a different line so it's clearer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
# sudo pip3 install tqdm

import time
import tqdm

records = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

with tqdm.tqdm(smoothing=0.1, total=len(records)) as pbar:
    for k, record in enumerate(records):
        time.sleep(1)
        pbar.update()
```

[image]

---

Its all relative, so lets do some generic math. :)

```
# sudo pip3 install tqdm

import time
import tqdm

total = 5000
_number_left = 5000
with tqdm.tqdm(smoothing=0.1, total=total) as pbar:
    relatively_done = 0
    relatively_done_sum = 0
    for k in range(0, 5000, 2):  # 0, 2, 4, ... 4998
        time.sleep(0.0005)
        _number_left -= 2  # input from some worker process for example
        absolutely_done = total - _number_left
        relatively_done = absolutely_done - relatively_done_sum
        relatively_done_sum += relatively_done
        pbar.update(relatively_done)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use enumerate to track your progress, e.g.:

```py
l = len(records)
for i, r in enumerate(records):
    # other stuff...
    w.writerow([id, code])
    # print progress
    pr = i / l
    if pr in (0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0): 
        print('Writing to disk... {:%}%'.format(pr))
```

Comment: This answer seems the simplest, but I get no output when running the code with your additions on a test file containing ten ContentItemIDs. Maybe this has something to do with the additional parameters in the `for` loop? The namedtuple object isn't something I'm very confident with yet.

Comment: Try commenting out this line: ```if pr in (0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0):```. It may happen that the progress never catches the exact values of 0.25, 0.5, etc... You might do a more sophisticated and robust check, e.g. ```if (pr >= 0.25 and pr < 0.27) or (pr >= 0.5 and pr < 0.52) or (pr >= 0.75 and pr < 0.77) or pr == 1.0:```

Answer (score 0):

[pure python solution] To print the progression in percent and who stay on the line (i.e. that don't consume all the screen), you can do as follows:

```
        [...]
        count = 1
        total = len(record)
        for i, r in enumerate(records):
            id   = r.ContentItemId
            url  = "https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/library/ephemera/" + id
            req  = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
            code = req.status_code
            w.writerow([id, code])
            print("%.2f \t\r" % (i/total), end='')
```